# Internet Performance Monitoring Tool With WebUI

Tags: networking, internet

I am looking for a tool which will monitor my internet speeds periodically. I have seen things such as [Netflow Analyzer](https://www.manageengine.com/products/netflow/) but it looks like those focus on local bandwidth. I just want to see what my internet performance looks like over time.

Something with a web UI would be great because I would like to install this on my server. Anyone aware of such a tool?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may try [PRTG](https://www.paessler.com/prtg?gclid=Cj0KCQjwjoH0BRD6ARIsAEWO9Dt6mrIuOKwThMziAOmn6xRNRhyUvfrsgZQQkZMreuSQnaf0plIt59waAgkWEALw_wcB) or [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/) for free. Both of them are great tool!